# Can NDB put_multi help to save write operations?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, quota

The GAE document says that

> Because each get() or put() operation invokes a separate remote
>   procedure call (RPC), issuing many such calls inside a loop is an
>   inefficient way to process a collection of entities or keys at once.

I don't understand what exactly `an inefficient way` means. Can it help me to save write operations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it can't reduce write operations. However it can save RPCs.

Think about what is going on. When you call put() the RPC sends data and waits for a response , inside that call is a write to the datastore.

If a single RPC has a 30ms overhead  no matter what it is doing (I am making that number up for the sake of the argument) . and the write takes an additional 20ms.  Then each put() call takes 30ms rpc round trip + 20ms for the actual write = 50ms.

If you perform 100 put() calls in a loop then it will take 5000ms.

However, if you use put_multi() or db.put([list of entities]) then you will only have a single RPC.  This means a single 30ms RPC and 100 * 20ms writes.  Which comes out at 2030ms.  Ok the numbers aren't accurate and a single RPC with 100 entities will take a little longer than a with just one.  But you get the idea.

Comment: OK, thanks! And since I use `put_async()` the benefit is even less.

Comment: Possibly, though you would need to check if put_async will batch under the hood, otherwise you will still incur multiple rpc's (which cost) even if it doesn't appear to take as long.  There is a put_multi_async as well.

Comment: I think it would be worth profile (appstats) to see how much impact.  Each RPC does add up.

Comment: Where's the RPC cost? Can't find it here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/pricing?csw=1#Billable_Resource_Unit_Cost. Thanks.